# Guidelines for returning collections from public functions

Tags: api-design, haskell

### The Problem

Imagine you have a function in a public API that needs to return some kind of collection. Its type is something like

```
foo :: a -> b
```

where `b` is some kind of collection.

As far as I can see, there a three major kinds of collections -- at least those are the ones used most often:

1. Sequences (order matters, there might be duplicates)
2. Sets (order doesn't matter, no duplicates)
3. Maps (elements are key-value pairs, order doesn't matter, no duplicate keys)

What should you use for `b` in these three cases?. I have considered three alternatives, but there might be more.

---

### A. Just return a list

In this alternative, you just return lists for everything:

1. `foo :: a -> [c]`
2. `foo :: a -> [c]` (and document that there are no duplicates)
3. `foo :: a -> [(k, c)]` (and document that there are no duplicate keys)

The advantage of this is that the client can construct any collection they want from the returned list.

The disadvantage for 2 and 3 is that

- the type does not have the "no duplicates" guarantee and that the client has to do more work to get a set/map out of it
- construction of the list in 2 and 3 might be less efficient, because something like a `union` for sets is obviously faster than for lists
- you might construct an intermediate list (depends on the problem at hand).

### B. Return a concrete type matching the guarantees

In this alternative, you return a type that precisely matches the guarantees you are giving:

1. `foo :: a -> [c]` (or maybe `foo :: a -> Data.Sequence.Seq c`)
2. `foo :: a -> Data.Set.Set c` (lazy or strict?)
3. `foo :: a -> Data.Map.Map k c` (lazy or strict?)

The advantage is that the type accurately describes the guarantees you want to express and that the client doesn't have to do any extra work.

The disadvantage is that you're locked into a particular implementation. If you just want to switch to a different set implementation, you break the public API. That might be a good thing in case of a switch between lazy and strict, because those can matter for correctness of the calling code. But in general you want to be able to swap implementation without your clients noticing.

### C. Let the client decide

In this alternative, you just constrain the return type with a type class and let the client decide on the concrete type:

```
1. `foo :: Sequence b c => a -> b`
2. `foo :: Set b c => a -> b`
3. `foo :: Map b c k => a -> b`
```

(The names I used are from [collections-api](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/collections-api-1.0.0.0/docs/Data-Collections.html), but it doesn't really matter.)

The advantage of this is that the client can choose which collection type to use.

The disadvantage is that you have no control over the collection you construct anymore. This means, e.g., that you cannot assume laziness or complexity of inserts.
Another problem is that the client can get ambiguous types, e.g., when they immediately fold the returned collection:

```
Data.Foldable.fold (foo whatever)
```

Now `b` is ambiguous.

---

Are there any other alternatives? What would you recommend?

I **don't** want `foo` to be able to return a different kind of collection on every call. 
The three cases considered are completely separate.

In each case the question is "if I have a function that needs to return an X, what type should it have?" where X can be a sequence, set, or map (or any other kind of collection you can think of).

Comment: is there nothing like unfoldM ?

Comment: Does `foo` can return any type of collection in any calls? or some calls return some specific type?

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa: that's alternative C.

Comment: @Simon: no, foo is just a placeholder here. I'm asking what to do if a function returns a sequence, what if it returns a set, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to declare an opaque `newtype` that hides the actual implementation and implement type classes that could be useful to your clients and that you can guarantee to be stable in the future. And you can also export functions that allow conversion of your data type to some standard ones.

This forces clients to use only functions or instances you provide and document, and also allows clients to use standard API such as `Foldable`:

```
module MyMod
    ( MyResult()
    , resultToSet   -- by hiding the internals and exporting the accessor
                    -- explicitly, you can always change the internal
                    -- representation and replace the accessor a function
                    -- with the same signature
    ) where

import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import qualified Data.Set as S

newtype MyResult a = MyResult { resultToSet :: S.Set a }

-- For example, your clients could use `Foldable` and `Monoid` instances:

instance F.Foldable MyResult where
    foldMap f = F.foldMap f . resultToSet

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (MyResult a) where
    mempty = MyResult mempty
    mappend (MyResult x) (MyResult y) = MyResult (x `mappend` y)
```

**Update:** If you later decide to change the internal representation to `HashSet`, the module would look like this:

```
module MyMod
    ( MyResult()
    , resultToSet   -- by hiding the internals and exporting the accessor
                    -- explicitly, you can always change the internal
                    -- representation and replace the accessor a function
                    -- with the same signature
    ) where

import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Hashable
import qualified Data.HashSet as HS
import qualified Data.Set as S

newtype MyResult a = MyResult { resultToHashSet :: HS.HashSet a }

-- For example, your clients could use `Foldable` and `Monoid` instances:

instance F.Foldable MyResult where
    foldMap f = F.foldMap f . resultToHashSet

instance (Eq a, Hashable a) => Monoid (MyResult a) where
    mempty = MyResult mempty
    mappend (MyResult x) (MyResult y) = MyResult (x `mappend` y)

-- Reimplementation of functions from the previous version

resultToSet :: (Ord a) => MyResult a -> S.Set a
resultToSet = S.fromList . HS.toList . resultToHashSet
```

The external interface is almost the same (the only change is that the `Monoid` instance now has slightly different constraints).

---

Another way that would give clients much flexibility is to let the collection be fully abstract. This can be nicely expressed using [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). The output of your function will be a polymorphic monoid, we just need a way how to create singletons. For example, if we want to generalize `enumFromTo`, we could write

```
enumCol :: (Enum a, Monoid c) => a -> a -> ((a -> c) -> c)
enumCol f t singleton = mconcat . map singleton $ enumFromTo f t
```

It's then the client responsibility to use a monoid with effective `mappend` operation.

With `RankNTypes` the return type could be also encapsulated using `type` as

```
type OutCol e c = (Monoid c) => (e -> c) -> c
```

The additional benefit is that in *some* cases this can be very effective thanks to laziness. For example, the following returns immediately:

```
enumCol 0 (10^20) (First . Just)
```

Comment: Doesn't your first alternative still have the problem that I have to decide what type of set `resultToSet` returns? You're second alternative is basically C in my question. Do you know any packages that follow that approach?

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Yes, you need to decide it, but you're not bound by the implementation. If you later decide to change the internal representation from `Set` to `HashSet`, you can just replace `resultToSet` by a more sophisticated conversion. So clients won't be dependent on the internal representation.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt No, I'm not aware of any packages that follow the second approach. I agree, it's similar to C, with the small difference that by supplying the `singleton` function explicitly, we can avoid ambiguous types (at the cost of client having to supply it every time and perhaps also `RankNTypes`).

Comment: If I replace Set by HashSet, won't that require a recompilation by clients?

Comment: @TobiasBrandt I updated the example showing the changes when replacing `Set` with `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have three (or N) separate functions, one for each of the three (or N) separate types of collections?

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. I'm asking how functions returning some particular kind of collections should be treated. The three cases are not the same function.

Comment: I dunno man. Sounds like this should be on http://cs.stackexchange.com =)